# .Net Process hosting leaking c++ (Unmanaged Code)

Tags: c++, .net, memory, memory-leaks

I have a .net service that loads up massive amount of code in c++ which have a memory leak.

if i'll try to use .net profiles (i.e. dotMemory), i won't be able to found the memory leak, because they are meant to find leaks in managed code

if i were to use Unmanaged code profiles, i'll encounters the same problem.

How can i profile a c++ code inside .net process?

Comment: Interesting. Would attaching you profiler to the service process after it was started work?

Comment: I can profile the .net service but all i see are the simple classes, that have the only purpose of hosting the c++ code, and an unmanaged code invoked

Comment: If your C++ code is in a DLL, ApplicationVerifier should be able to diagnose it.